# How to format these strings in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matrix, format

I have some problem about `.format()` when I use it in `matplotlib` plotting: Suppose, I have a matrix `A = np.column_stack([[0, 1], [-1, 0]])` and I have to display this matrix in my plot. Also this matrix may be changed as per my need. So I use the **following code** but it gives error. Can you please tell me how to do this task. Also I faced a similar problem when I try to display a vector like, `$2\hat{i}+5 \hat{j}$`:

**I try the following for the matrix:**

```
A = np.column_stack([[0, 1], [-1, 0]])
matrix = r'$\left( \begin{array}{ll} {a11} & {a12} \\ {a21} & {a22} \end{array} \right)$'.format(a11=A[0][0], a12=A[0][1], a21=A[1][0], a22=A[1][1])
plt.title(matrix)
```

**Output:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-12cfe5180092> in <module>()
     12 
     13 A = np.column_stack([[0, 1], [-1, 0]]) #Matrix
---> 14 title = r'$\left( \begin{array}{ll} {a11} & {a12} \\ {a21} & {a22} \end{array} \right)$'.format(a11=A[0][0], a12=A[0][1], a21=A[1][0], a22=A[1][1])
     15 
     16 #Plotting:

KeyError: 'array'
```

**I try the following for the vector:**

```
x = [2,3]
plt.text(2,3,'${a}\hat{i}+{b}\hat{j}$'.format(a= x[0], b=x[1]))
```

**Output:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-31281b09369d> in <module>()
     32 
     33 
---> 34 plt.text(2,3,'${a}\hat{i}+{b}\hat{j}$'.format(a= x[0], b=x[1]))
     35 
     36 #plt.title(title, y = 1.03)

KeyError: 'i'
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: It gives : ```KeyError: 'array'```

Comment: As the error says, you are not passing a keyword argument of `array` to the `format` method and yet you have `{array}` in your formatting string.

Comment: @blhsing...then how to fix it..

Comment: You define "Things ... {array} ... " and then call '.format(...)' on it. Then you must tell '.format(array="Value)' to fill in the '{}'.

Comment: @MadMike...I don't get you...

Comment: "My name is {name}, I live in {place}".format(name="MadMike", place="Europe") #Every {} within the String is placeholder. The call '.format()' expects you to him a value. You are using placeholders where you don't give a value and python tells you so

Comment: But see that I have given the value also......```.format(a11 = A[0][0]..)```..still it gives error

Comment: But you don't have `array=value` in your `.format()`...

Comment: I added it like.format(array=value, a11=..)....but it gives: NameError: name 'value' is not defined

Comment: Yes because you do not have a variable set to `value`. It was an example. You need to replace 'value' with whatever you need `array` to be set to. See my answer for further clarity.

Comment: There are two problems. (1) matplotlib mathtext does not support environments, i.e. in order to use `\begin{array}` you need to use true tex (2) Curly brackets need to be escaped if they are not be used as format placeholders. I closed as duplicate of respective questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used your second example to provide an answer for simplicity to explain the issue.

```
x = [2,3]
plt.text(2,3,'${a}\hat{i}+{b}\hat{j}$'.format(a= x[0], b=x[1]))
```

This returns a `KeyError: 'i'` because the array variable specified in the string as `{i}` has not been set in your `.format()` statement. It was also fail if you just add `i` to your `.format()` statement as `j` has not been specified either.

See the following for a working example:

```
x = [2,3]
plt.text(2,3,'${a}\hat{i}+{b}\hat{j}$'.format(a= x[0], b=x[1], i="SOMETHING", j="SOMETHING"))
```

**SUMMARY: Everything inside a `{}` needs to be set in your `.format()` statement.**

Comment: Thank you so much....it works